# To what ‘this shift’ in the following context refers?

Tags: reference

> In his vast writings, Heidegger provides the ontological axis to
> support referencing a norm, if only indirectly through a measure set
> by the propri- etorship of human dwelling (and the strife between
> world and earth). But he does not follow up on a corollary
> presupposition (at the root of our dwell- ing), namely, that the
> freedom exercised in offsetting the monopoly of human interests, e.g.,
> by “letting-be,” can provide an example to denote a “good” in a
> positive sense. In order to have any “practical implications,” the
> norm must encapsulate a new context for the creation of laws, the
> dynamic for their for- mulation and enactment that has historically
> gone under the heading of “jus- tice.” In addressing today’s
> environmental crisis, we experience the transition from the
> establishment of ready-made laws to the source of their origination,
> the threshold of **this** **shift**, of which Heidegger was aware when he
> alluded to a “measure.” Unlike Heidegger, we can more directly trace
> the correlation between distinguishing a measure and the breakthrough
> of a new context of justice. We have the advantage (and also the
> disadvantage of living through the crisis) of discovering the concrete
> implementation of a measure, which is illustrated by the balancing and
> counterbalancing of human and non-human interests through an array of
> practices aimed at safeguarding the earth, its habitats, and nature.
> Such environmental practices stand forth not only as concrete actions,
> but as signposts (e.g., the most primitive gestures) to the formation
> of a socio-biotic community and governance by laws designed to
> confront the global forces of technicity.(Heidegger’s Ecological Turn
> Community and Practice for Future Generations,
> By Frank Schalow, p2.)

Comment: It means what the dictionary says it means.

Comment: @Lambie I didn’t ask about the meaning of something here!

Comment: "It means" means; the word shift means.

Comment: This is an absolutely insane choice of text for anyone whose knowledge of English is less than perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*this shift*" refers back to "*the transition from the establishment of ready-made laws to the source of their origination*"

In my view this passage is overly densely written. It also uses a good deal of jargon or technical terminology familiar to people in the specific field, but possibly confusing to others, such as its use of "measure" and "norm".

---

When you give a quote like this, please give the source (title and author) and if possible a link.

Answer (score 1):

a shift is another word for a "transition".  "This shift" refers to " the transition from the establishment of ready-made laws to the source of their origination"

Comment: The shift is after the fact. The transition is the process.